# Dart how to search a list with different values

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the model below, which includes the subject name and other values.

```
  class SubjectModel{
    String chapter;
    String lesson;
// more values
    }
```

I'm getting data as a list `List<SubjectModel> subjects`. To receive results depending on the `chapter` and `lesson`, I need to filter (search) the list. I wrote a function with that intention.

```
List<SubjectModel> subjects;  // where i receive data
searchSubjects(){
List<SubjectModel> result; // for adding result
if(searchcontroller.text.isEmpty){          // this is a texteditingcontroller
result = subjects;
} else{
// I need to get results based on both chapter and lesson
results = ? 
 }
}
```

Sometime both the chapter and lesson may have same name
eg:- chapter  `Addtion` , lesson `addition`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where` method of `List` for that:

(`term` is the search term, substitute it with `searchcontroller.text` in your case)

```
final results =
    subjects.where((item) => item.chapter == term || item.lesson == term);
```

This is case sensitive and for full match. If you need case insensitive:

```
final results = subjects.where((item) =>
    item.chapter.toLowerCase() == term.toLowerCase() ||
    item.lesson.toLowerCase() == term.toLowerCase());
```

If you need partial match (case sensitive):

```
final results = subjects.where((item) =>
    item.chapter.contains(term) ||
    item.lesson.contains(term));
```

If you need partial match (case insensitive):

```
final results = subjects.where((item) =>
    item.chapter.toLowerCase().contains(term.toLowerCase()) ||
    item.lesson.toLowerCase().contains(term.toLowerCase()));
```

It is also possible to search for results that **begin with** the search term. Just replace `contains` with `startsWith`.